# SharePoint 2016 Managed Navigation Import CSV Parameter Mapping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, import, managed-navigation, term, csv

I am interested in importing my managed navigation information from an existing site into another sharepoint site (we are creating environments for testing and production, so we want them to mirror one another).  Research that I've done so far, has shown that there are only certain fields that can import and I was curious if anything has changed.  We are interested in importing not only our term sets (which are nested), but also child target information (such as if we have a term-driven page assigned to a specific Friendly-URL).

my question: can I identify what fields may be needed in order to accomplish this?  At this time, is it even possible?  Information I've found has shown that as of a few years ago, it isn't, and the Mircosoft Documentation hasn't been helpful for anything other than the fields that you can find in the import sample file that they provide.  I would be open to creating my own script to manipulate additional fields, but I would need guidance on what those fields may be.  Any direction offered towards resources or more information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone.  I found the answer in the Import-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData command, I was not using it properly.  I used this site for reference: [link](http://www.herlitz.nu/2014/11/05/restoring-a-backed-up-site-collection-with-managed-navigation-in-another-web-application)